# Does the windows phone 7/8 support application-level sockets?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to implement a chat application and I would like to know  if the windows phone 7/8 supports  application-level sockets  ?

Is there any sample code for this ?

Comment: You mean sockets as in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows Phone from 7.1 supported TCP/UDP sockets. Windows Phone 8 supports additionally socket connections via Bluetooth, and other proximity technologies as well as web sockets.

A chat sample is show in this tutorial on UDP broadcast sockets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286407(v=vs.105).aspx

There are other samples available for IM-style clients too.